# How to find cells with img tag using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to select cells from table only with img tag and change the styles using only JS.

```
<table border="1" id="table1">
<tr>
<td id="0"><img src="background.jpg"></td><td id="1"></td><td id="2"></td><td id="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to use it in my form but I don't know how to make it work.
I tried this (in it I wanted to look img by id entered in form but i know - it  isn't working)

```
 function form1() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img");  
    var y = document.getElementById('formu').value;
 if (x=y) {

    console.log(x)

}




<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="ship"></label>
        <input type="text" id="formu" name="ship" value="" />
    </fieldset>

    <input type="button" onclick="check()" value="fire!">
</form>
```

If in this form I'll put id cell where exists tag img I want to be change styles that cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript you can select the images like this:

```
var tdImages = document.querySelectorAll('td > img');
```

Then iterate over them and use the parentNode

```
var td, index = 0, length = tdImages.length;
for ( ; index < length; index++) {
    td = tdImages[index].parentNode;
}
```

Here is a fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/y1vseo5t/

EDIT: So you want to have a user enter an ID in the input and from that determine if that table data element has an image, if it does change some styling on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/y1vseo5t/1/

selectors can't start with a number so I changed your ids on table data elements to be td0, td1...

If you must stick with numbers as the first character in the ID here is another solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/y1vseo5t/2/

Comment: Nice! But I have only one more request. 
How to connect it with form?
I check form value using this  
var y = document.getElementById('formu').value;

Comment: I am happy to help but I am not sure I understand what you mean by connect it with the form? I don't think value is a legal attribute/property on form. So what value are you attempting to get from the form? Maybe show some more HTML above so I can see how you are using form.

Comment: OK, so you want a user to enter a value in the input and then check if there is an image with the same id in the table? Whats the end goal here?

Comment: Change cell style if user put to the form same ID which is cell that cell where exists img tag

Comment: Added two solutions for you above with fiddles.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: Hey and if you feel this answer completely answered your question and was helpful would mind accepting it as the answer? I am trying to build up rep points for site privileges. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is best done in jQuery, where you can use the `has` selector

```
$("td").has("img").each(function() {
});
```

Here is the JavaScript solution

```
var cellsWithImage = document.querySelectorAll("td > img");

for (var i = 0; i < cellsWithImage.length; i++) {
    cellsWithImage[i] = cellsWithImage[i].parentNode;
}
```

Note that we have to use loops because the array methods `filter` and `map` do not work on DOM collections.

I have another note regarding your code. You are using the `document.getElementsByTagName` function, but that returns a collection not a DOM object. You need to put the object's index inside of parentheses to reference a particular image.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]       // Returns first image
```

Comment: But how to make it using only JS?